# FuncPtrTab to Method

Tags: c++, pointers, methods, tabs

I'm having a hard time trying to make this work. I'm trying to execute a method
stocked in a method pointer tab.

here is my example :

```
void class1::fct1();
void Class1::fct2();

void Class1::manageFct()
{
    static const void (*ptrFuncTab)[] = {
        &Class1::fct1,
        &Class1::fct2
    };
    opCode = 0;
    ptrFunctab[opCode](); //==> call Cpu::fct1()
}
```

i understand that i have to put the instance in which i want to apply
the fct pointed. But how ?
Does anyone knows what i'm doing wrong ?

Thanks,
Cuva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
typedef void (Class1::*MemFn)();

static const MemFn ptrFuncTab[] = {
    &Class1::fct1,
    &Class1::fct2
};
```

What you were using is called **pointer-to-function**; what I'm using is called **pointer-to-member-function**.  And they're not the same thing.

Use this function table as:

```
Class1 c;
(c.*ptrFuncTab[0])();
```

Or if you want to use pointer, then

```
Class1 *pC = new Class1();
(pC->*ptrFuncTab[0])();
```

Comment: Hello,

when i compile it says

Comment: When i do that it says : 
error: invalid use of qualified-name ‘Cpu::ptrFuncTab’ at the line of static const void ...

Comment: @cuva: did you use type `()` ? See carefully!

Comment: I have this :
void   Class::execute()
{
  static const void ((*Class::ptrFuncTab)())[] = {
    &Class::add,
    &Class::sub
  };

Comment: yeah, thanks it works !
But now im having trouble calling it...
this->*(tabFuncPtr)[opCode]() doesnt work

Comment: @cuva: Good. Now accept it as solution to your problem. :-)... see I'm calling the function using the function table!

Answer (score 0):

Once you edit like Nawaz said, you call a function in the table like this:

```
Class1* ptr = new Class1();
(ptr->*ptrFuncTab[opCode])();
```

for a pointer, and like this:

```
Class1  ref;
(ref.*ptrFuncTab[opCode])();
```

for a reference.